# I cannot make the paragraph preprocess work at all

Tags: theming, 9

I have a Barrio-based subtheme and I am rewriting from scratch an old Drupal 7 site to be moved to Drupal 9 (my first Drupal 9 site). All pages in the new site is built by different paragraphs and mostly there aren't problems so far.

A few paragraphs need to fetch content from an external API service (that I myself have written). I tried to add this function both in zzz.theme and theme-settings.php and it seems it's not even called. (*zzz* is the theme name.)

```php
function zzz_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  die("Finally got here!");
}
```

Heck, I have even made some syntax errors on purpose but it still stubbornly gives the page without errors nor changes in the variables.

I don't even know where or what to look for, php-fpm www error log is empty. Am I missing the finger in my eye, or is it something more subtle (like deprecation)?

Drupal 9 documentation is quite sparse so far, though it should be the same as with Drupal 8.

Comment: [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/9.0.x) hasn't changed. `I have even made some syntax errors on purpose but it still stubbornly gives the page without errors` That's a red flag . Something else must be a miss. Is the correct theme enabled? Did you flush the cache? Re-start your local dev? <-- rare, but had that happen to me twice with Lando.

Comment: I have done all of those except restarted dev. All my changes in say twig templates on that theme work fine, so the correct theme should be enabled. And yes, I have cleared cache after every change and then a few times just for the joy of it ;) Been developing for Drupal for 4-5 years now...

Comment: To add to what @NoSssweat said, also having the same function in two files is a red flag. When visiting the settings page for the theme, it would throw an error about a redefined function.

Comment: I have a virtual development server and - behold! - restarting it seems to have solved the problem! Never ever happened before... Thank you all for the suggestions and allowing me to go on